Shopware 6 Security Plugin Error "The parameter "SwagPlatformSecurity.activeFixes" must be defined"
I use dockware and have Shopware 6.4 and the Shopware Security Plugin installed there.
When I open the store I get the following error message:

The parameter "SwagPlatformSecurity.activeFixes" must be defined.

I can't find a solution either via google or the Shopware Community.
My Configuration:

Shopware 6.4.17.2
SwagPlatformSecurity Shopware 6 Security Plugin 1.0.25



Do you try to reinstall the plugin?

Yes...same issue

what version do you use? Have you cleared the cache?

Delete var/cache/* and it will work

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
